# Link 2 store procedures in 1 crystal report

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports

Hi, 
In a report called ICD_PrivateHospital, I have designed to show output to two table from two stored procedures.

- 1st stored proc: usp_RPT_Private
- 2nd stored proc: usp_RPT_Private2.

I have created both the stored procs and it is executing successfully. I also have designed the Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2008. I have added both the stored procs in the crystal report with no error.

I only want to show the top 20 records. It is running successfully when I add the fields and parameters from the first stored procedure, but when I add the 2nd stored procedure's fields into the report, duplication occurs for both the results in stored proc 1 and stored proc 2.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

check the linking? because of linking can be the issue.. if you are not sure of the linking then check the option `select Distinct Records` to eliminate the duplicate records.

Comment: distinct is not working since im using select top 20 rows_number()

Comment: in that case check the linking